# Asp.net Javascript Avoid Duplicate values from DropDownList based On Other DropDownList

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a 10 DropdownList, I want to avoid duplicates, the problem is that if I choose dropdowndownlist randomly the seventh Dropdownlist I choose six, the following remaining dropdownlist will appear 1 and I want to avoid that, what I want is to remove duplicate values or maybe set to null if duplicate values appears, here is my code  I hope you can help with the javascript[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tKer.png)......

```
<div>
    <table>
    <asp:DropDownList ID = "ddl1" runat="server"  >
        <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>            
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID = "ddl2" runat="server" >
       <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>   
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID = "ddl3" runat="server" >
       <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>     
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID = "ddl4" runat="server" >
       <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>   
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID = "ddl5" runat="server" >
       <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>   
    </asp:DropDownList>
         <asp:DropDownList ID = "ddl6" runat="server" >
       <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>   
    </asp:DropDownList>
         <asp:DropDownList ID = "ddl7" runat="server" >
       <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>   
    </asp:DropDownList>
         <asp:DropDownList ID = "ddl8" runat="server"  >
       <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>   
    </asp:DropDownList>
         <asp:DropDownList ID = "ddl9" runat="server"  >
       <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>   
    </asp:DropDownList>
         <asp:DropDownList ID = "ddl10" runat="server"  >
       <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>   
    </asp:DropDownList>
        </table>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save"    
         OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>

        <script type="text/javascript">

   var Lists = [
        document.getElementById("ddl1"),
        document.getElementById("ddl2"),
        document.getElementById("ddl3"),
        document.getElementById("ddl4"),
        document.getElementById("ddl5"),
        document.getElementById("ddl6"),
        document.getElementById("ddl7"),
        document.getElementById("ddl8"),
        document.getElementById("ddl9"),
        document.getElementById("ddl10")

   ],
        nbLists = Lists.length;


   // Binds change events to each list
   for (var iList = 0; iList < nbLists; iList++) {
       Lists[iList].onchange = RemoveItems(iList);
   }


   function RemoveItems(iList) {
       return function () {
           var value = [];

           // Add the selected items of all previous lists including the one changed
           for (var jList = 0; jList <= iList; jList++) value.push(Lists[jList].options[Lists[jList].selectedIndex].text);


           // Hide in all succeeding lists these items
           for (var kList = iList + 1; kList < nbLists; kList++)
               HideItems(kList, value);
       }
   }


   // Hide items selected in previous lists in all next lists
   function HideItems(iList, value) {
       var nbOptions = Lists[iList].options.length,
           nbValues = value.length,
           found;

       if (nbValues === 0) return;

       for (var iOption = 0; iOption < nbOptions; iOption++) {
           // Find if this element is present in the previous lists
           found = false;
           for (var iValue = 0; iValue < nbValues; iValue++) {
               if (Lists[iList].options[iOption].text === value[iValue]) {
                   found = true;
                   break;
               }
           }

           // If found, we hide it
           if (found) {
               Lists[iList].options[iOption].style.display = "none";
               Lists[iList].options[iOption].selected = "";
           }
               // else we un-hide it (in case it was previously hidden)
           else
               Lists[iList].options[iOption].style.display = "";
       }
   }
        </script>
```

Comment: In what way does the code you've written not work as expected?

Comment: Sir if you can see that if choose alternately the selected values then later I will choose again a previous value it will duplicate, you can test my code too see it.. thanks

Comment: `"you can test my code too see it"` - You have *entirely* misunderstood how Stack Overflow works.  We are not your personal debuggers.  When *you* test your code, where/how *specifically* does it fail?  Of course you're able to choose duplicate values, because there exist duplicate values in the selections.  What do you expect would prevent that from happening?  In what way have you tried to prevent that from happening, and how is that attempt not working as expected?

Comment: Sir What I what is that, how can I avoid those duplicate values, I want to choose the selected value in respective dropdownlist. so if I save it to database I will get the exact value, sorry for my mistake, and my accent I'm an asian..

Comment: sir may I ask where is youre code so I can test it thank you.

Comment: Again, you have ***entirely*** misunderstood how Stack Overflow works.  If you want someone to write code for you, hire a programmer.  If you've been sitting there waiting for me to write your program for you, you're going to be waiting for quite some time.

Comment: I'm sorry sir, I won't ask anymore, I'm just asking, I'm a beginner, you are a great man I see you're reputation... and I had only one reputation... I'm not saying to write a program... I thought you could show some link , an Idea or advise, another way to do it... I misunderstood stack overflow.... and you're a great man...I'm just nothing.. hope you can be more great...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use clienside validation first with a `CustomValidator`?

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="There are duplicate values" ClientValidationFunction="noDuplicates"></asp:CustomValidator>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function noDuplicates(oSrc, args) {
                var ddl1 = document.getElementById('<%= ddl1.ClientID %>').selectedIndex;
                var ddl2 = document.getElementById('<%= ddl2.ClientID %>').selectedIndex;

                if (ddl1 != ddl2) {
                    args.IsValid = true;
                } else {
                    args.IsValid = false;
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Ok sir I will try your code..

Comment: Thanks you sir for the Idea... it really helps